# Why we ignore off-diagonal elements in partition function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, partition-function, trace

In quantum statistical mechanics, the density operator is
$$ \rho = \exp(-\beta H_0)/Z $$

where

$$Z = \text{Tr} (\exp(-\beta H_0)) \, .$$

Why do we take the trace over only diagonal elements and ignore off diagonal elements?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we do not choose to "take the trace over only diagonal elements", but rather the trace is defined that way. Note that the trace is an [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariants_of_tensors), just as the determinant, and hence it does not depend on the basis chosen to describe the system. It means that using a different basis, which would in general change both the diagonal and the off-diagonal terms, would result in the same partition function. If we use the basis in which the operator is diagonal, we learn that its trace is just the sum of all its eigenvalues.

Now, we know that the partition function is just the sum of the Boltzmann factor of the eigenstates of the system. There is a mathematical theorem that shows that, if $E_i$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$, then the eigenvalues of the matrix $\exp(A)$ are given by $\exp(E_i)$. It derives that the eigenvalues of the $\exp(-\beta H)$ operator are linked through the same relation with the eigenvalues of $H$. Computing the partition function of $\exp(-\beta H)$ thus reduces to computing its trace, as this is exactly equal to the sum of its eigenvalues.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. Sure, the trace is invariant to the basis, but so are many other functions. What makes the trace special here?

Comment: @AlNejati I have edited the question to explain a bit better why the partition function can be expressed as a trace of the $\exp(-\beta H)$ operator.

Comment: @Ir1985  You mentioned that "If we choose basis in which operator is diagonal we learn that trace is just the sum of diagonal elements" But  how we know that in which basis the operator is diagonal and which it is not?

Comment: Beside trace means the sum over the diagonal elements. What about off diagonal elements?why we ignore them while calculating partition function?

Comment: @herry we do not need to know for which basis the operator is diagonal, as we already know that the trace of an operator is *independent* on the basis we are using, meaning that taking the trace always yields the same result, regardless of the basis. It's not that we "ignore" the off-diagonal elements, it's just that we know that the partition function is the sum of $\exp{-\beta E_i}$, which happens to be the trace of the $\exp{-\beta H}$ operator.

Comment: But doesn't trace mean the sum over the diagonal elements?

Comment: @herry yes it does, but as I have already written, the trace is an *invariant* of the operator. It means that, even though it is counterintuitive, its value is *independent* on the basis.

Comment: then how we can say that $exp(-\beta H)$ is diagonal in energy basis

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because we define the expectation of operator $A$ as:$$<A>=\sum_{n}{<n|e^{-\beta H}A|n>=tr(\rho A)},$$where $$\rho = exp -\beta H,$$ and the quantum edition of partition function$$Z=\sum_{n} exp -\beta E_{n}=tr \rho.$$